# Prove $\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}y^j \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \binom{n+j}{j} \frac{x^n}{n!n!}A_n(y) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(1-y)^{-n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!n!}A_n(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading [a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X76900352)

On page 223, they used the property that

$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}y^j \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \binom{n+j}{j} \frac{x^n}{n!n!}A_n(y) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(1-y)^{-n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!n!}A_n(y)$

But I don't know how to prove that property. I intend to try to use Cauchy product but it doesn't because the second sum also depends on $j$.

Could you please give me some hints to prove that property?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is easy to show by induction that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+j}{j}y^j=\frac{1}{(1-y)^{n+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Do we need any condition for $y$ ? @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: What is $A_n$ ?

Comment: @BenjaminWang there is a reference in the question ... Pipnap: Combinatrialists tend to treat these things as formal power series & totally dodge questions of convergence, but $ \mid y \mid \le 1$ if you like.

Comment: I proved it. Thank you very much